# How do i push back the new input of constructor to the default input of the constructor in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a class to implement graph in c++ as below. This is the default coding and it cannot be modified.

```
Graph(vector<Edge> const &edges, int N)
{
    // construct a vector of vectors of Pairs to represent an adjacency list
    vector<vector<Pair> > adjList;
    // resize the vector to N elements of type vector<Pair>
    adjList.resize(N);

    // add edges to the directed graph
    for (auto &edge: edges)
    {
        int src = edge.src;
        int dest = edge.dest;
        int weight = edge.weight;

        // insert at the end
        adjList[src].push_back(make_pair(dest, weight));
    }

    this->N = N;
}
```

In the main program, i have the default input for the constructor as below. I have to check whether the graph has a cycle or not. If it does not, the program has to generate random edges until cycle is found in the graph. The default graph does not contain cycle and it has the edges as below:

```
vector<Edge> edges =
    {
        // (x, y, w) -> edge from x to y having weight w
        { 0,1,6 }, { 0,2,12 }, { 1,4,9 }, { 3,4,1 }, { 3,2,4 }
    };
```

I tried appending the random edges to the default graph using the code below. However,it does not work.

```
do
{
  src=rand()%5;
  dest=rand()%5;
  weight=rand()%20;

  vector<Edge> edges1{
    {src, dest, weight}};

  Graph graph1(edges1,N);
  graph.push_back(graph1);

  if(graph.isCyclic())
  {
    //print the graph
  }
}while(!graph.isCyclic());
```

I think the push_back() function is not used properly. Anyone knows how? Thanks.

Comment: you indicate the bug may be `Graph::push_back`; share the code for that function then please.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn no, I was trying to use the vector::push_back() function that does not need to be defined. For example: (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vectorpush_back-vectorpop_back-c-stl/)

Comment: Actually, `Graph(vector<Edge> const &edges, int N)` could be simplified to `this->N = N;` as `adjList;` is a **local** variable... typo from copy paste, else that constructor is wrong and should be fixed.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it does not work".

Comment: @qwertyuiop You are trying to use vector push_back, but graph1 is not a vector.

Comment: @qwertyuiop Ask yourself why on a program that needs only one graph, you have declared two of them? `graph` and `graph1`. Seems to indicate you are taking the wrong approach. But without seeing more of `Graph` is hard to suggest what the right approach is.

Comment: why in this line vector<vector<Pair> > adjList; you are directly push_back vector<pair> without the outside vector?

Comment: Why do you expect to be using `vector::push_back` on a `Graph`? And why are you trying to add a `Graph` to another `Graph`? Shouldn't you be adding an `Edge`?

Comment: Note to everyone; this code is derived from [here](https://www.techiedelight.com/graph-implementation-using-stl/). However, it doesn't define the `Graph::push_back(vector<Edge>)` being used.

Comment: @molbdnilo ok, i tried doing this:**Graph graph(edges1,N);
      edges.push_back(edges1);**. the error says no matching function for call to ‘std::vector::push_back(std::vector&)’.

Comment: @qwertyuiop That doesn't look right either, edges and edges1 are both vectors.

Comment: @qwertyuiop You have to look at the classes you have Graph, Edge and vector<Edge> to see what the possibilities are. The most significant question (which you haven't addressed yet) is whether you can modify an existing Graph by adding a new edge, or whether each Graph must be created complete from a vector of edges. You need to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information provided it seems the following would work.

```
vector<Edge> edges = ...;
for (;;)
{
    int src=rand()%5;
    int dest=rand()%5;
    int weight=rand()%20;
    Edge new_edge{src, dest, weight};
    edges.push_back(new_edge);
    Graph graph(edges, N);
    if (graph.isCyclic())
    {
        //print the graph
        break; // exit the loop
    }
}
```

But this code recreates the graph each time round the loop, so there may be something more efficient possible.

**UPDATE**

Seems the following might work, it avoids recreating the graph each time

```
vector<Edge> edges = ...;
Graph graph(edges, N);
for (;;)
{
    int src=rand()%5;
    int dest=rand()%5;
    int weight=rand()%20;
    graph.adjList[src].push_back(std::make_pair(dest, weight));
    if (graph.isCyclic())
    {
        //print the graph
        break; // exit the loop
    }
}
```